# How to unbold the font used to show messages in the tkinter.messagebox.showinfo() widget?

Tags: python, tkinter

Presently, the messages that are shown in the `tkinter.messagebox.showinfo()` defaults to using bold fonts. When used to show messages about the GUI, I find it to be quite an eyesore. How can I change the weight of the message font of this widget?

Comment: @stovfl Yes it does.

Comment: ***"Yes it does"***: Consider to close this question as duplicate.